# MongoDB aggregation condition translated to JAVA driver

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm relatively new to MongoDB and I'm currently working with java towards a "find by most tags matching" solution to information within a collection.

I'm stuck now trying to translate a MongoDB shell operation to the JAVA driver version (this sintaxis is part of the definitions needed )

`$cond:[{$eq: ["$tags", 200]}, 1, 0]`

What would be a correct JAVA implementation for the sentence above?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Whatever the $cond object where in your aggregation operation, to build it to should do something like this:

```
BasicDBList eqList = new BasicDBList();
eqList.add("$tags");
eqList.add(200);

DBObject eqObject = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
    .add("$eq", eqList)
    .get();

BasicDBList condList = new BasicDBList();
condList.add(eqObject);
condList.add(1);
condList.add(0);

DBObject condObject = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
    .add("$cond", condList)
    .get();
```

I'm confusing about your aggregation operation, could you give more details?

Comment: It looks like the OP just needed help creating the DBObject, but to answer your question, [$cond](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/cond/) is one of the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) expressions (like a SQL [IF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function).