# Aggregation using MongoDB java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB java driver 3.2.2 to do some aggregation operations, but I'm not sure if something could be achieved through it.

The original query in MongoDB is:

```
db.getCollection('report').aggregate({
$group: {
    _id: "$company_id",
    count: {
            $sum: {
                    $cond: [{
                            $eq: ["$idcard.status", "normal"]
                        },0,1]
                }
            }
    }
})
```

I have no idea of how to put the "$cond" as a parameter of "$sum" operator in Java driver in the code section below:

```
        AggregateIterable<Document> res = col.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
            group("$company_id",
                    sum("count", ...)
            )));
```

I've searched the [official document](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/builders/aggregation/) about this with no result, anyone has experience of doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3.x drivers

Using BsonDocument :  Type Safe Version

```
BsonArray cond = new BsonArray();
BsonArray eq = new BsonArray();
eq.add(new BsonString("$idcard.status"));
eq.add(new BsonString("normal"));
cond.add(new BsonDocument("$eq", eq));
cond.add(new BsonInt64(0));
cond.add(new BsonInt64(1));

AggregateIterable<BsonDocument> aggregate = dbCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        group("$company_id",
                sum("count", new BsonDocument("$cond", cond))
    )));
```

Using Document - Less Code but Not Type Safe

```
List cond = new ArrayList();
cond.add(new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList("$idcard.status", "normal")));
cond.add(0);
cond.add(1);

AggregateIterable<Document> aggregate = dbCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        group("$company_id",
                sum("count", new Document("$cond", cond))
        )));
```

Comment: Finally I use the Document class for this case, thanks for the precise explanation of the difference!

Answer (score 0):

To use $cond in Java use ArrayList.

```
{ $cond: [ { $eq: ["$idcard.status", "normal"] },0,1]
```

// To Acheive this - [ "$idcard.status", "normal" ]

```
ArrayList eqArrayList = new ArrayList();
eqArrayList.add("$idcard.status");
eqArrayList.add("normal");
```

// To Acheive this - [ { $eq: [ "$idcard.status", "normal" ] } , 1, 0 ]

```
 ArrayList condArray = new ArrayList();
 condArray.add(new BasicDBObject("$eq", eqArrayList));
 condArray.add(1);
 condArray.add(0);
```

// Finally - { $cond: [ { $eq: ["$idcard.status", "normal" ] } , 1, 0 ] }

```
BasicDBObject fullCond = new BasicDBObject("$cond", condArray);
```

Also see: [MongoDB aggregation condition translated to JAVA driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898014/mongodb-aggregation-condition-translated-to-java-driver)

Comment: BasicDBObject is for 2.x driver version. BsonDocument and Document is recommended for 3.x driver version.